# Content-available silent notification not calling correct AppDelegate method

Tags: ios, networking, apple-push-notifications

I've added some logging in to a feature for downloading quite large content bundles using content-available notifications to our app, and I'm noticing some behaviour which is a bit strange, and not sure how to handle it correctly:

1. If the notification is received when the app has been in the background for a long time the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` method is correctly called as far as I can see.
2. Occasionally (Yet to work out when this is, but seems it's maybe within a certain time after leaving the app) instead of the above method being called, the app is launched in the background and application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called with the remoteNotification key, and the above method is never called.

Is scenario 2. here expected behaviour? I can't see anywhere online (Apple forums, docs, SO) saying that this can happen, but it evidently is!

If 2. happens, my plan is to detect if the notification was a silent content-available notification and run the same background download logic (pseudo-code) like so:

```swift
var launchedByContentPush: Bool = false
if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable : Any], let aps = remoteNotification["aps"] as? [AnyHashable : Any] {
    launchedByContentPush = aps.keys.count == 1 && aps["content-available"] as? Int == 1
}

if launchedByContentPush {
 // 1. Don't do normal app-setup stuff which shouldn't be done
 // 2. Download content
}
```

Is this a sensible plan, or could I end up breaking the stuff under 1. in some cases of user actually launching the app?

Just to 100% confirm: I AM receiving content-available notifications, everything is working on that front, so this isn't a configuration issue as far as I'm aware of!

Shown are some logs, one of a session which worked flawlessly, and the other is for a session where `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is called

**INCORRECT**

```
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [INFO] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Initialising Content Controller
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Setting app build date to 2 April 2020 at 19:42:56
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | <REDACTED>
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: languages
Error: The folder “languages” doesn’t exist.
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: languages
Error: The folder “languages” doesn’t exist.
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [INFO] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (AppState) | application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions with keys: [__C.UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey(_rawValue: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey)]
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: languages
Error: The folder “languages” doesn’t exist.
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: languages
Error: The folder “languages” doesn’t exist.
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: languages
Error: The folder “languages” doesn’t exist.
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | `appLaunched` called
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Checking for app upgrade
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Optionally checking for updated content
2020-04-02T19:01:03Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Checking for updates with timestamp: 1585848393.0
2020-04-02T19:05:48Z [INFO] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (AppState) | applicationWillEnterForeground
2020-04-02T19:05:48Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Checking for updates failed: The request timed out.
2020-04-02T19:05:49Z [INFO] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (AppState) | applicationDidBecomeActive
2020-04-02T19:08:33Z [INFO] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (AppState) | applicationWillResignActive
2020-04-02T19:08:34Z [INFO] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (AppState) | applicationDidEnterBackground
```

**CORRECT**

```
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [INFO] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Initialising Content Controller
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Setting app build date to 2 April 2020 at 19:42:56
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Base URL configured as: <REDACTED>
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: languages
Error: The folder “languages” doesn’t exist.
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: languages
Error: The folder “languages” doesn’t exist.
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [INFO] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (AppState) | application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions with keys: []
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: languages
Error: The folder “languages” doesn’t exist.
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: languages
Error: The folder “languages” doesn’t exist.
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: languages
Error: The folder “languages” doesn’t exist.
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | `appLaunched` called
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Checking for app upgrade
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Optionally checking for updated content
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Checking for updates with timestamp: 1585848393.0
2020-04-02T23:19:12Z [INFO] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (AppState) | applicationDidBecomeActive
2020-04-02T23:19:13Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No update found
2020-04-02T23:20:36Z [INFO] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (AppState) | applicationWillResignActive
2020-04-02T23:20:37Z [INFO] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (AppState) | applicationDidEnterBackground
2020-04-02T23:35:57Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Push notification received, checking if it's a `content-available` push
2020-04-02T23:35:57Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | content-available == 1 sending notification off to `ContentController`
2020-04-02T23:35:57Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | `appLaunched` called
2020-04-02T23:35:57Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Checking for app upgrade
2020-04-02T23:35:57Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Handling content-available notification
2020-04-02T23:35:57Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Making sure notification bundle isn't after a landmark publish this app shouldn't receive
2020-04-02T23:35:57Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No landmark timestamp provided in notification
2020-04-02T23:35:57Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Checking notification timestamp against latest on-disk bundle version
2020-04-02T23:35:57Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Downloading content-available bundle with timestamp: 1685827838.0
2020-04-02T23:35:57Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Downloading bundle: <REDACTED>
Destination: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CBCB1B36-D853-4E36-B766-9F3F31158DF7/Library/Application%20Support/StormDeltaBundle/
2020-04-02T23:36:04Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Handling events for background url session: 784B47D4-C2B6-4310-ADD5-8539BE40A447-60638-000035ACB72C6167
2020-04-02T23:36:04Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Starting background request controller
2020-04-02T23:36:06Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Unpacking bundle...
2020-04-02T23:36:06Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | data.tar.gz read to data object
2020-04-02T23:36:06Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Attempting to gunzip data from data.tar.gz
2020-04-02T23:36:07Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Gunzip successful
2020-04-02T23:36:09Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Bundle tar saved to disk
2020-04-02T23:36:09Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Attempting to untar the bundle
2020-04-02T23:36:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Untar successful
2020-04-02T23:36:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Verifying bundle...
2020-04-02T23:36:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Loading manifest.json into JSON object
2020-04-02T23:36:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Loading manifest.json as dictionary
2020-04-02T23:36:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | app.json exists
2020-04-02T23:36:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | manifest.json exists
2020-04-02T23:36:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Verifying pages
2020-04-02T23:36:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Verifying languages
2020-04-02T23:36:12Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Verifying content
2020-04-02T23:36:13Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Bundle is valid
2020-04-02T23:36:13Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Cleaning up `data.tar.gz` and `data.tar` files
2020-04-02T23:36:13Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Copying bundle
From: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CBCB1B36-D853-4E36-B766-9F3F31158DF7/tmp/StormDeltaBundle/
To: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CBCB1B36-D853-4E36-B766-9F3F31158DF7/Library/Application%20Support/StormDeltaBundle/
2020-04-02T23:36:26Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Beginning excluding from backup files in directory: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CBCB1B36-D853-4E36-B766-9F3F31158DF7/Library/Application Support/StormDeltaBundle/content
2020-04-02T23:36:29Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Beginning excluding from backup files in directory: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CBCB1B36-D853-4E36-B766-9F3F31158DF7/Library/Application Support/StormDeltaBundle/languages
2020-04-02T23:36:29Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Beginning excluding from backup files in directory: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CBCB1B36-D853-4E36-B766-9F3F31158DF7/Library/Application Support/StormDeltaBundle/data
2020-04-02T23:36:31Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Beginning excluding from backup files in directory: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CBCB1B36-D853-4E36-B766-9F3F31158DF7/Library/Application Support/StormDeltaBundle/pages
2020-04-02T23:36:31Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Beginning excluding from backup files in directory: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CBCB1B36-D853-4E36-B766-9F3F31158DF7/Library/Application Support/StormDeltaBundle
2020-04-02T23:36:31Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Removing bundle in directory: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CBCB1B36-D853-4E36-B766-9F3F31158DF7/tmp/StormDeltaBundle/
2020-04-02T23:36:31Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Update complete, Refreshing language
2020-04-02T23:36:31Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: languages
Error: The folder “languages” doesn’t exist.
2020-04-02T23:36:31Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: languages
Error: The folder “languages” doesn’t exist.
2020-04-02T23:36:31Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | Removing bundle in directory: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CBCB1B36-D853-4E36-B766-9F3F31158DF7/tmp/StormDeltaBundle/
2020-04-02T23:36:33Z [DEBUG] | com.threesidedcube.ThunderCloud (ContentController) | No files exist in streamed bundle directory subfolder: pages
Error: The folder “pages” doesn’t exist.
```

Comment: Yes, scenario 2 is expected. When your app is suspended it can be jettisoned at any time if iOS determines that it needs memory.

Comment: So if my app is jettisoned then it will call `applicationDidFinishLaunching` instead of the specified delegate method? Okay cool, as long as I know that's expected I can deal with that appropriately! Would be nice if that were documented by Apple, but expecting a bit too much there I think :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul's comment above is correct, this is expected behaviour that the didFinishLaunching method will be called if the app has been terminated for any reason before receiving the `content-available` notification.